# Show/hide controls on flexslider on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, flexslider

I have a [flex slider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) with prev/next arrows, pretty standard. I hide the arrows on the page load and only want them to appear when the user hovers over the carousel info.

Here's my code:

```
$(".flex-container.home ul.flex-direction-nav").hide();
$(".flex-container.home .flexslider").hover(
    function(){
        $(".flex-container.home ul.flex-direction-nav").fadeIn();
    },
    function(){
        $(".flex-container.home ul.flex-direction-nav").fadeOut();
    }
)
```

The problem now is that when the user actually hovers over the arrow itself, it fades out, since technically I'm asking it to do so. I've tried to add some !important css to the ul.flex-direction-nav css styles but it doesn't stop the fade out from happening.

Comment: Have you got a jsFiddle by any chance?

Comment: Let me see about getting one going

Comment: ok - first jsFiddle :) http://jsfiddle.net/h4krS/1/

Comment: hmm. I see it working on my end... ugh

Comment: Don't worry it's working! I'll have a look at it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your code to the following. I've modified your selectors and used **[fadeToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/)** to save you writing extra code.

Here is the new version, which works how you specified you would like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".flex-container.home ul.flex-direction-nav").hide();
  $(".flex-container.home").hover(function () {
         $(" ul.flex-direction-nav").fadeToggle();
  });    
});
```

[**Here is a working jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/h4krS/7/).

Answer (score 0):

```
    pauseOnHover:true,  //this option working good
```

Comment: Your answer will be more useful if you include an explanation of what it does and how it solves the problem.  You'll get more upvotes, too.  :)

Answer (score 0):

below css solved the issue for me-

```
.big-slider .flex-direction-nav {opacity: 0 !important;}
.big-slider .flex-direction-nav:hover {opacity: 1 !important;}
```